# satchmo: ccavenue payment gateway integration

Tags: satchmo

I would like to integrate CCAvenue payment gateway wth Satchmo cart.
Presently, this module is not available in Satchmo framework for ready installation.
Looks like I need to develop a custom module for the same. If anyone has any information/details regarding this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at this
http://ngoinabox.mahiti.org/ccavenue.pdf